# how to vertically align to center navigation options on react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

this is my code:

```
Welcome.navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: <Text style={theme.fonts.header}>Welcome</Text>,
  headerTitleStyle: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    textAlignVertical: "center"
  },
  headerRight: (
    <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
      <Block flex={false}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          source={require("../../assets/images/Icon/Menu.png")}
          style={{ width: 20, height: 24 }}
        />
        <Badge
          size={13}
          color={theme.colors.accent}
          style={{ position: "absolute", top: -4, right: -4 }}
        />
      </Block>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
};
```

You see i have used textVerticalAlign & alignSelf to center for headerTitleStyle and used alignSelf 
center for headerRight, still no effect and this is the result of the code which you it's like aligned on bottom:

[image]

I also tried this still not working:

```
headerStyle: { 
  alignItems: 'center'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give [flex : 1] to header title style

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for Navigation Options:

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const params = navigation.state.params || {};
    return {
      title: "Title",
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        flex:1,
        alignSelf: 'center',
      },
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff6500'
      },
      headerLeft:(<View></View>),
      headerRight: (<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end',marginRight:15 }}>
          <Text style={{justifyContent:"center"}}>btn</Text>
      </View>)
    }
  };
```

Code ScreenShot:[image: Code ScreenShot:]

Answer (score 0):

You would do this in `headerTitleContainerStyle` instead of `headerTitleStyle`.

Vertically center:

headerTitleContainerStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' }